# How to get carriage return without line feed effect in Eclipse console?

Tags: java, eclipse, console, carriage-return, linefeed

If I

```
System.out.print("something\r");
```

at console, I have cursor back at the beginning of line, and finally after

```
System.out.print("something\r");
System.out.print(" any\r");
```

I have

```
 anything
```

typed.

But at Eclipse console I get

```
something
 anything
```

as if it treated `\r` as CR/LF.

How can I setup this?

Comment: Seems like an unresolved bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=76936

Comment: While I can understand the use of this, I ask why you need it to work in Eclipse. It might be inconvenient, but at some point I would imagine that you will just have to test it in a console window, presumably its final execution place anyway. Eclipse is capable of running external programs for testing - I have to do it all the time since my program runs via .bat file. (Sorry I can't be of more help.:/ )

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As Nishant already pointed out in the comments, **[you've found a bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=76936)** here.

This bug initially was reported in 2004 *(>9 years ago!?!!)* and this bug seems **not to be fixed very soon** (or ever). I tested it on several Eclipse version, even on *Eclipse Juno SR2*, and the bug is still there.

Comment: Does not work in Eclipse Neon Release (4.6.0) (Build id: 20160613-1800)

Comment: As of Eclipse 2020-03, the bug is *still* present. I guess some bugs are literal cockroaches!

Comment: The bug is fixed now.  See another answer.

Answer (score 13):

The bug is fixed by now (Eclipse 2020-03).
Just go to

```
Window ➺ Preferences ➺ Run/Debug ➺ Console
```

and make sure that both checkboxes

```
Interpret ASCII control characters
```

and

```
Interpret Carriage Return (\r) as control character
```

are enabled.

Comment: great. it only too them 16 years

Answer (score 3):

It finally seems to be fixed in Mars!

```
Version: Mars Release (4.5.0)
Build id: 20150621-1200
Used Java: jre1.8.0_60
```

Your code

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("something\r");
        System.out.print(" any\r");
    }
}
```

Output

```
 anything
```

Comment: Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)
Build id: 20150924-1200

Output:
something
 any

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in Neon.  Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3) Build id: 20170314-1500

Comment: weird ask: how can I make it to treat "\n" as "\r\n" again? (version Oxygen)

Comment: Bug was fixed at some point but fix was reverted again due to some problems - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=76936#c72. Right now it does not work Version: Oxygen Release (4.7.0)
Build id: 20170620-1800

Comment: Broken again in Eclipse Photon 4.8.0 (20180619-1200)

Answer (score 0):

Move the mouse pointer into the console area,
click on the right mouse button, a popup menu opens.
Click on "Preferences..." item.
Check "Interpret Carriage Return (\r) as control character" box.
Click on "Apply and Close" button.