# Why is Eclipse setting carriage returns(\r) when Carriage return+newline(\r\n) is supposed to be the value

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, newline

I've been trying to format some text using java on a windows virtual machine. Text from the file looks like:

```
      Local

      RPLSTRGKD2

      Rcpt/Disb
```

I'm trying to replace this text block with just

`Local Rcpt/Disb`

When searching for this block of text in the document originally started with just \n for newline however I switched to using \r\n when I found out that is a how it should be on windows.

On further debugging through eclipse I found that the text was actually:

```
Local\r\r RPLSTRGKD2\r\r Rcpt/Disb
```

This code will be deployed to Unix server so I think I may need to change the \r to \n before deploying the code.

I have 2 questions:

1. Is there any explanatation for why \r is being used instead of \r\n which is expected on windows.
2. Is there any way to deploy this to a Unix server where \n is supposed to be used instead of \r without having to change the code for deployment?

Comment: Are you saying that you already have a file that has `\r\r` in it, or that you're trying to write a file with `\r\n` but getting `\r\r` instead? If you're writing the file out, you need to show the code you're using to write it. IIRC the default Writer behavior is to translate `\n` into whatever the platform's EOL sequence is.

Comment: Possibly related : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=329981 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14792478/how-to-get-carriage-return-without-line-feed-effect-in-eclipse-console

Comment: I'm reading a file that I had assumed was \r\n due to the way windows handles new lines and because `System.getProperty("line.separator") == "\r\n"` however I am seeing \r\r  and wondering why it is \r\r and not \r\n and how I can protect myself when moving to a unix environment.

Comment: Protecting yourself isn't a big deal when you're matching. Use a regex to do the match and simply search for `[\r\n]*` where you expect a newline - will cover all scenarios.

Comment: Thanks I ended up just using a regex to match instead of String comparison. I wanted to maintain the same pattern that was being used in the existing code but realized wasn't worth my time. If you reply with an actual answer I will mark it correct.