# how to print String one after another in java

Tags: java, string

I want to know that I want to print string one after another but in a particular time interval.

Everything is fine.

I want to know that when second string print override the first one and third override the second and so on..

How can I do this?

This is my code :

```
public class StringTest {

  public static void main(String args[]) {

    String arr[] = { "mahtab", "hussain", "yasir", "azmi", "saif" };

    int l = arr.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      System.out.print(arr[i]);
      try {
        Thread.sleep(5 * 1000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what does 'override the first one and third override the second' mean?

Comment: You're already doing that.

Comment: Where is the problem? What error are you getting? The current code should be printing those names one after the other with a 5 second delay.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I print to the same line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939802/how-can-i-print-to-the-same-line)

Comment: What you need is escape sequences for you terminal. Console Java program  do not directly manipulate screen.

Comment: i mean it show on by one not all first show then second but overide  the first one

Comment: what is the output you expect?

Comment: i want that when out is print then comes like first print "mahtab" then delete mahtab and print hussain like this.....

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this with the carriage return `\r`.

```
System.out.print(arr[i]+"\r")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
  for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  System.out.print(arr[i]);
  try {
    Thread.sleep(5 * 1000);
    for(int j=0;j<arr[i].length;j++){
        System.out.print("\b");
    }
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Comment: it is not working what i want

Answer (score 0):

To remove the last character from the screen, you can use `System.out.print("\b")`