# Java: Display changing text on output

Tags: java

Currently, my program prints to `System.out`:

```
Processing line 1 of 3...
Processing line 2 of 3...
Processing line 3 of 3...
```

Is there any way to have it replace the line numbers, instead of printing a new line?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439799/whats-a-good-java-curses-like-library-for-terminal-applications

Comment: Without using a library, you could just print a '\r' (Return to the start of the line) and thus overwrite what you just printed.

Comment: System.out.print(), didn't write at the same line?...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I print to the same line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939802/how-can-i-print-to-the-same-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are some hacks you can try, but none of them are guaranteed to work everywhere. Escape characters such as `\b` (backspace) can erase the last character and `\r` (replace) can erase the last output.

It may or may not work (depending on IDE), but you could try:

```
System.out.print("Hello");
Thread.sleep(1000);
System.out.print("\rWorld");
```

However, generally a Swing box should be used (dynamically updating GUI) to measure progress. See [Progress Bars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html).