# How to over print in console in Java

Tags: java

I wrote a program to send the mails one by one. I would like to print how many mails it sent . But I like to print in single places instead of 1  2  3....  or in new line. I would like to print like if it sent 1 it need to print 1 after sent 2nd then it have to erase 1 and have to print 2 in same place.

Can you help me please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I print to the same line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939802/how-can-i-print-to-the-same-line)

Comment: Did you try `\b` for backspace?

Comment: show us what have you tried.

Comment: please share what you tried with the so many answers already in SO, and the duplicate thread linked here, so that people can just look at that and help you out

Answer (score 2):

To clear the screen just type:

```
System.out.print('\u000C');
```

then print updated value.

for every call first it will clear the screen and then it will print the required value.

**You can also try ANSI Escape Codes:**

If your terminal support them, try something like this:

```
System.out.print("\033[2J\033[1;1H");
```

You can include `\0333[1;1H` to be sure if `\0333[2J` does not move the cursor in the upper left corner.

**More specifically:**

```
•033 is the octal of ESC
•2J is for clearing the entire console/terminal screen
•1;1H moves the cursor to row 1 and column 1
```

Comment: Please explain the meaning of parameter that you used, instead of plain code.. In addition, I tried ur code like this , but it gives output of `01234` printed along with some special characters in Eclipse console. `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   System.out.print('\u000C');
   System.out.print(i);
  }`

Comment: its an ANSI escape code. are you using windows os?

Comment: yes, please update in ur answer to be more understanding..