# How to print out in a column vs a row

Tags: java, loops

Hi im new here and fairly new to java in school ive got a program here that ive got working its just now printing the way it should hers the program

```
import java.util.*;
public class stars
{
   public static void main(String args[]){  
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the starting Value");

    for( int star=keyboard.nextInt(); star>=1; star--)
    { for( int starTwo=star;starTwo>=1; starTwo--)
        {
      System.out.println("*");
    }
    }

    }    
}
```

it prints right now in a straight column going down it has the correct number of "*" just in the wrong format. 
I need it so row 7 has 7 , row 6 has 6 row 5 has 5 ect. all the way to 1.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Show us your input, expected result, expected output

Comment: Please understand System.out.println means to print to a new line.
You need to use System.out.print("*");

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a duplicate Please go through this [How can I print to the same line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939802/how-can-i-print-to-the-same-line)

Please understand 
System.out.println means to print to a new line.

You need to use 
System.out.print("*");

```
for (int star = keyboard.nextInt(); star >= 1; star--) {
    System.out.println("");
    for (int starTwo = star; starTwo >= 1; starTwo--) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
}
```

Example

```
    for (int star = 7; star >= 1; star--) {
    System.out.println("");
    for (int starTwo = star; starTwo >= 1; starTwo--) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
}
```

prints

```
*******    
******
*****
****
***
**
*
```

Comment: This only prints it out in a row yes but not like i want like i said i need so it when the input is say 7 it print a row of 7 then a new row of 6 then a new row of 5 ect all the way to a row of 1.

Comment: you my friend have not even checked the result from the code

Comment: Thank you missed a line of the code that you changed.