# i need to print the statement continuously in java not in next line

Tags: java

i need to print the print statements continuously.

For example:

if execute these statements:

```
System.out.println("HI");
System.out.println("HELLO");
```

the default output will be like this:

```
HI
HELLO
```

But i need to print:

```
HI HELLO
```

how to print these statement continuously in java?

Comment: use `print` with space instead of `println`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I print to the same line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939802/how-can-i-print-to-the-same-line)

Comment: Your **first stop** should be [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
System.out.print("HI");
System.out.print(" ");
System.out.print("HELLO");
```