# Java countdown print in same point of screen

Tags: java, printing

I want to countdown a number from 10 to 0(for example) in the same line and same point
I use following code in Java :

```
\033[2J\033[;H          ,
```

but in terminal the cursor always goes 
at the top left point of screen.
How to fix it?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Please see this it will help full I hope thanks,                                       https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939802/how-can-i-print-to-the-same-line

Comment: Yes ,it helped me.Thanks...

Comment: Please make sure to close this question once you got answer or update the answer for the question because it’s help to others